# Please undelete a meta post on videos

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions

There is a user who recently had his account deleted.  This causes various things to run, in particular a down voted post gets deleted.  When this down voted post is a question, it deletes the question and answers.

In this case, the post was about including youtube videos on the main site.  While the post was down voted (disagreement), it shouldn't be deleted - its something that someone else will ask again in the future.  It is better to have a record of the early policy decisions and questions asked than to have them disappear.

Please undelete the post.  Suspecting this was going to happen, I +fav'ed it earlier so any user who can see deleted posts should be able to go to my [favorites](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/36/michaelt?tab=favorites) and see it with that red background.  A mod could undelete it, or sufficient number of users with the undelete privilege (1k for beta sites) could do so.  As its a deleted post, I can't really go there and flag it (I can't see it).

Comment: I voted to undelete the post, as I think it is conducive to the community. Others have to vote for undeletion, unless a mod helps out. 1+.

Comment: I restored the post